# Найти совпадения в полях объектов

Tags: java, объекты

У меня есть `List<Document> listOfDocuments = new ArrayList<>()` объектов.

Вот сами объекты:

```
book (author, title, publisher, annotation, text)
article (author, title, journal, year, text)
wiki (link, title, text)
```

List listOfDocuments = new ArrayList<>();

Мне нужно найти объекты, у которых будут совпадать `title` и/или `text`.
Все объекты наследуются от класса `Document`.

Проблема - я не понимаю, как пройтись по всем документам и их полями. Нужно создать какой-то цикл или есть какой-то метод?

Comment: А как вы добавляете элементы в ваш `listOfDocuments` ?

Comment: @lDrakonl listOfDocuments.add(new Book(...))

Comment: все объекты наследуют класс Document?? Вы имели ввиду, что у вас есть классы book, article, wiki, которые наследуют Document или что?

Comment: @RomanAlexandrovich Да. Есть класс Document и Book, Article, Wiki наследуются от него

Comment: ну пробегайтесь циклом, и проверяйте поля

Comment: А что делать с объектом, который уникальный - он игнорируется? И если все же есть два объекта с одинаковым текстом и названием, например, book и wiki, они оба куда-то должны записываться\выводиться? Что с этими документами делать? Спрашиваю поскольку здесь возможно задачка на коллекции данных, которые не поддерживают дубликат, например, `Set<Document>` в таком случае задача хотя бы будет привязана к реальному миру - "Создать результирующий список с объектам с уникальными полями title и text".

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski Ничего не было сказано про уникальность, по этому просто вывел все повторяющиеся элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    for (int k = i + 1; k < list.size(); ++k) {
        if (list[i].title.equals(list[k].title) ||
            list[i].text.equals(list[k].text) {
                ++count; //нашли пару
         }
    }
}
```

Код работает при условии, что вы вынесли все поля в класс Document, иначе полиформизм не позволит нам обратится к этим полям. Так же поля лучше сделать private и написать соответствующие get методы.

UPD0: спасибо Pro100Denysko за указание ошибки со сравнением.

UPD1: НЕ забываем переопределить метод equals objectа для корректного сравнения.

Comment: Все круто, но единственное что строки нужно сравнить не `==`, а `equals`.

Comment: да вы правы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Да, если пользоваться стандартными средствами языка программирования, то циклом:

```
for (Document item : listOfDocuments) { 
    // проверка item.title и item.text
}
```

Comment: не уверен, но возможно хотелось найти все пары объектов, у которых совпадают `title` или `text`

Comment: @diraria да, все

Comment: @Pro100Denysko таки и в чем проблема организации указанного цикла?